# How to convert json array to individuals entry

Tags: json

I have json data like following way:

```
[2, 1, ["55", "54"]]
```

How can i get 55 and 54

Thanks

Comment: Which language ? client side javascript ? server side ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arr = [2, 1, ["55", "54"]];

arr[2][0] // 55
arr[2][1] // 54
```

Answer (score 0):

var a = [2, 1, ["55", "54"]];

This is an array. So, you access them by index.

here a[2]=["55", "54"]

To access 55

a[2][0]

To access 54

a[2][1]